# Bash string split

Tags: string, shell, split, explode

I have a log file that I'm reading line by line.

**Possible input:**

```
" 0:00 InitAuth: \auth\0\auth_status\init\auth_cheaters\1\auth_tags\1\auth_notoriety\1\auth_groups\ \auth_owners"
```

**Wanted Output:**

```
$TIME = 0:00
$TYPE = InitAuth:
$DATA = \auth\0\auth_status\init\auth_cheaters\1\auth_tags\1\auth_notoriety\1\auth_groups\ \auth_owners
```

Or *$Output[0], $Output[1], $Output[2]*
I don't care if it will be 1 array or 3 vars.

At first i was thinking about splitting that line into 3 vars and use space like delimiter, so i was trying to search for sh replacement for PHP command `explode(' ', $input, 3);` but then i found line like this:

```
"1728:32ClientUserinfoChanged: 0 n\ThunderBird\t\3\r\2\tl\0\f0\ \f1\ \f2\ \a0\0\a1\0\a2\0"
$TIME = 1728:32
$TYPE = ClientUserinfoChanged:
$DATA = 0 n\ThunderBird\t\3\r\2\tl\0\f0\ \f1\ \f2\ \a0\0\a1
```

And there is no space between Time and Type info.
So I want to know, how should i split that text now ?

Also I'm novice in Shell and I'm googling every possible command.

Comment: One my "linux" friend is helping me with that, and he send me this:
output=`echo $input | sed 's/^[^:]*:.. \?//'`
But it will only output Type & Data and ignore/skip TIME.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along this line might help you get desired output:

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]+:[0-9]{2})([a-zA-Z ]+:)(.*)/$TIME:\1\n$TYPE:\2\n$DATA:\3/'
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~] echo "1728:32ClientUserinfoChanged: 0 n\ThunderBird\t\3\r\2\tl\0\f0\ \f1\ \f2\ \a0\0\a1\0\a2\0" | gsed -r 's/([0-9 ]+:[0-9]{2})([a-zA-Z ]+:)(.*)/$TIME:\1\n$TYPE:\2\n$DATA:\3/'
$TIME:1728:32
$TYPE:ClientUserinfoChanged:
$DATA: 0 n\ThunderBird\t\3\r\2\tl\0\f0\ \f1\ \f2\ \a0\0\a1\0\a2\0

[jaypal:~] echo "0:00 InitAuth: \auth\0\auth_status\init\auth_cheaters\1\auth_tags\1\auth_notoriety\1\auth_groups\ \auth_owners" | gsed -r 's/([0-9 ]+:[0-9]{2})([a-zA-Z ]+:)(.*)/$TIME:\1\n$TYPE:\2\n$DATA:\3/'
$TIME:0:00
$TYPE: InitAuth:
$DATA: \auth\0\auth_status\init\auth_cheaters\1\auth_tags\1\auth_notoriety\1\auth_groups\ \auth_owners
[jaypal:~]
```

Comment: That's great, Thank you man.
But i wanted to add that to vars.

Answer (score 0):

So here is what i wanted and it works as well as I need, it's good. :)

Thanks Jaypal.

```
TIME=`echo $LINE | sed -r 's/([0-9]+:[0-9]{2})(.*)/\1/'`
TYPE=`echo $LINE | sed -r 's/([0-9]+:[0-9]{2})([a-zA-Z ]+:)(.*)/\2/'`
DATA=`echo $LINE | sed -r 's/([0-9]+:[0-9]{2})([a-zA-Z ]+:)(.*)/\3/'`
```

I guess that someone would truncate that :D

Comment: You can shorten it like this - 

`TIME=$(sed -r 's/([0-9]+:[0-9]{2})(.*)/\1/' <<< "$LINE")`